# Adding an integer number to a Unicode character - What does this do?

Tags: c#

I am learning C# in the beginners level. I do not understand what adding an integer number to a Unicode character does. What does the addition do in the example below?

```
int amount = int.Parse(number.Text);
steps.Text = "";
string current = "";
do
{
    int nextDigit = amount % 8;
    amount /= 8;
    int digitCode = '0' + nextDigit;
    char digit = Convert.ToChar(digitCode);
    current = digit + current;
    steps.Text += current + "\n";
}
while (amount != 0);
```

Comment: Say what? What line confuses you?

Comment: I don't see anything related to Unicode in your code... except the fact that `char` represents a Unicode character, but it's mostly irrelevant here

Answer (score 0):

This code converts an octal number to a string.  If you are talking about the line:

```
int digitCode = '0' + nextDigit;
```

This line convert a single binary digit into a string digit.  If the binary value is 0, the char value will be `'0' + 1` or `'1'`.  It's a common and useful little trick.

In most character sets (Unicode, ASCII, UTF-x, etc), the characters for `'0'` thru `'9'` appear sequentially so you can create any of these digit characters by adding a numeric value 0 thru 9 to `'0'`.

Comment: it actually converts a decimal number (from a string) to an octal number (in a string) not the other way

Answer (score 0):

When adding a character and an integer, the character gets converted to the integer value that represents the character code.

So `'0' + nextDigit` is the same as `48 + nextDigit`.

The integer is then converted to a character, and then to a string. It could be done easier using the `ToString` method (as the integer is always between 0 and 7):

```
do {
  int nextDigit = amount % 8;
  amount /= 8;
  string digit = nextDigit.ToString();
  current = digit + current;
  steps += current + "\n";
} while (amount != 0);
```

Comment: Hi Guffa, I have tried the suggested code and received the error, Error 1 Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' Also one more error Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'. Does it mean that we need to always concerns the number to character then only we can assign into string? Ans when we convert number to character, we have to add the '0' + integer number then assign into character variable by converting.

Comment: @Karikalan: I used a string variable when testing the code, so use `steps.Text` instead of just `steps`. Better yet, declare a string variable to concatenate the result in, then assign it to `steps.Text`.